# How to insert array of data in to mysql database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

My problem is that an array of data is not inserted to the database only last data is inserted. So, how to insert whole data at a time after click save button? I am using Codeigniter framework.

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue because I am new to Codeigniter? Thank you.

Here is my Controller Part. Please review this code and let me know if something is incorrect.

```
                    function index(){
                        $this->session->set_userdata('top_menu', 'Attendance');
                            $this->session->set_userdata('sub_menu', 'teacherattendance/index');
                            $teacher_result = $this->teacher_model->get();
                            $data['teacherlist'] = $teacher_result;

                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('stime', 'In Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('etime', 'Out Time', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
                        $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
                        $this->load->view('admin/teacherattendance/attendenceList', $data);
                        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
                            } else {
                            $data = array(
                                    'in_time' =>$this->input->post('stime'),
                                    'out_time' => $this->input->post('etime'),
                                    'teacher_id' => $this->input->post('teacter_id'),
                                    //'teacher_name' => $this->input->post('teacher_name')
                                    ); 

                        $this->load->model('teacherattendance_model');
                        $insert_id = $this->teacherattendance_model->add($data);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">Attendance added Successfully</div>');
                               redirect('admin/teacherattendance');

                        }
                        }
```

Here is my Model Part. Please check. This project for school erp.

```
                    public function add($data) {
                            if (($data['id']) != 0) {
                                $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
                                $this->db->update('teacher_attendance', $data); // update the record
                            } else {
                                $this->db->insert('teacher_attendance', $data); // insert new record
                                return $this->db->affected_rows();
                            }
                        }
```

Here is my View Part, please check.

```
                # View 

                <style type="text/css">
                    @media print
                    {
                        .no-print, .no-print *
                        {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                    }
                </style>

                <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 946px;">  
                    <section class="content-header">
                        <h1>
                            <i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i> Teacher Attendance <small><?php echo $this->lang->line('student_fees1'); ?></small></h1>
                    </section>
                    <!-- Main content -->
                    <section class="content">
                        <div class="row">       

                            <div class="col-md-12">              
                                <div class="box box-primary" id="tachelist">
                                    <div class="box-header ptbnull">
                                        <h3 class="box-title titlefix"><?php echo $this->lang->line('teacher_list'); ?></h3>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/teacherattendance/import" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Bulk Upload Teacher Attendance" >
                                                <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Import Teacher Attendance
                                            </a>
                                        </div>     
                <div class="exportteacher">
                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/teacherattendance/exportCSV" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download Teacher Attendance" >
                                                <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Export Teacher Attendance
                                            </a>
                                        </div>                
                </div>
                                    <div class="box-body">
                                        <div class="mailbox-controls">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="table-responsive mailbox-messages">
                                        <div class="download_label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('teacher_list'); ?></div>
                                            <form role="form" id=""  class="addmarks-form"  method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/teacherattendance/') ?>">
                                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
                                                        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg') ?>
                                                    <?php } ?>  
                                                    <?php echo $this->customlib->getCSRF(); ?>
                                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>

                                                                    <th>
                                                                        Teacher Name
                                                                    </th>

                                                                    <th>
                                                                        Phone
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        In Time
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        Out Time
                                                                    </th>

                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                            <?php
                                                    $count = 1;
                                                                foreach ($teacherlist as $teacher) {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="teacter_id" value="<?php echo $teacher['id'] ?>">

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <th name="teacher_name">
                                                                            <?php echo $teacher['name'] ?>
                                                                        </th>

                                                                        <th>
                                                                            <?php echo $teacher['phone'] ?>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th>
                                                                            <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="stime" class="form-control timepicker" 
                                                                                          id="stime" value="<?php echo $value->starting_time; ?>">                                                                                      
                                                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th>
                                                                            <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="etime" class="form-control timepicker" id="etime" value="<?php echo $value->ending_time; ?>">
                                                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </th>

                                                                    </tr>
                                                              <?php
                                                    }
                                                    $count++;
                                                    ?>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="save_attendance" value="save_attendance"><?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?></button>
                                                </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="mailbox-controls">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
        //  This is Javascript Part so ignore please...
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>backend/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">                  
                <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>backend/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>          
                <script>    
                $(function () {

                        $(".timepicker").timepicker({
                            showInputs: false,
                            defaultTime: false,
                            explicitMode: false,
                            minuteStep: 1
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
                    function printDiv(elem) {
                        Popup(jQuery(elem).html());
                    }

                    function Popup(data)
                    {

                        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
                        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
                        frame1.css({"position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px"});
                        $("body").append(frame1);
                        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
                        frameDoc.document.open();
                        //Create a new HTML document.
                        frameDoc.document.write('<html>');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<head>');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<title></title>');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/dist/css/font-awesome.min.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/dist/css/ionicons.min.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/plugins/morris/morris.css">');


                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + base_url + 'backend/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">');
                        frameDoc.document.write('</head>');
                        frameDoc.document.write('<body>');
                        frameDoc.document.write(data);
                        frameDoc.document.write('</body>');
                        frameDoc.document.write('</html>');
                        frameDoc.document.close();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                            window.frames["frame1"].print();
                            frame1.remove();
                        }, 500);


                        return true;
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: simple use `$this->db->insert('table_name',$data)`

Comment: Please refrain from demanding a solution “ASAP” - that is very pushy, and generally not liked by people around here. Being new in a topic or having spend a day on it already is no excuse. We are not here to write your code for you, or completely fix your problem on our own. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly. You need to tell us what specifically you are having problems with first of all.

Answer (score 0):

I have this abit of a solution, maybe better if you make a model in core folder, for example,

Core_Model:

```
class Core_Model extends CI_Model
{
   protected $table = '';

   public function insertItem($in_data)
   {
      $this->db->insert($this->table, $in_data); //query for inserting
      $last_id = $this->db->insert_id(); //if you want to get the last id inserted

      return $last_id;
   }
}
```

My_Model

```
class My_Model extends Core_Model
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->table = 'my_table';
   }
}
```

In this way though, every table needs to be one Model, for example `table_user`, that should be one Model, probably name it `User_Model` or something, in that way every single time instead of making lots of insert functions you can just call the core insertItem() function for convenience.

Example

My_Controller

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   public function add()
   {
      $this->load->model('User_model');

      $data = array(
         'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
         'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
      );

      $this->user_model->insertItem($data); //since user_model extends the core file, it can access the method insertItem() as long as it is public
   }
}
```

Note: that this will only work with one table

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function mysql_insert_array($table, $data, $exclude = array()) {
    $fields = $values = array();
    if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
    foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
        if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
            $fields[] = "`$key`";
            $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
        }
    }
    $fields = implode(",", $fields);
    $values = implode(",", $values);
    if( mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($values)") ) {
        return array( "mysql_error" => false,
                      "mysql_insert_id" => mysql_insert_id(),
                      "mysql_affected_rows" => mysql_affected_rows(),
                      "mysql_info" => mysql_info()
                    );
    } else {
        return array( "mysql_error" => mysql_error() );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.